# training step and validation step different in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am using tensorflow callback for visualizing on tensorboard.

```
tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir='logs',
    histogram_freq=1,
    write_graph=True,
    write_images=True,
    update_freq='epoch',
    profile_batch=2,
    embeddings_freq=1,
    )
```

I am using simple model and using data pipeline as input to the model. Here feature layer contains the feature_columns of each feature:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    feature_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 12, activation='relu', use_bias = True, kernel_initializer= 'glorot_uniform', bias_initializer = 'zeros'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, activation='relu', use_bias = True, kernel_initializer= 'glorot_uniform', bias_initializer = 'zeros'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

I am using adam as optimizer, sparce categorical crossentropy as loss, and accuracy as metrics.
Here is my tensorboard graph:

[image]

```
red line = train   
blue line = validation
```

my problem is why it is showing training step less then the validation step.

Comment: Hi  @Aniket Bote,  Can you show the epoch configuration when training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the tensorflow documentation for [tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard), under arguments section for `profile_batch`, it is written as below -

`profile_batch`: Profile the batch(es) to sample compute characteristics. profile_batch must be a non-negative integer or a comma separated string of pair of positive integers. A pair of positive integers signify a range of batches to profile. By default, it will profile the second batch. Set profile_batch=0 to disable profiling. Must run in TensorFlow eager mode.

**As you have set `profile_batch=2`, thus it showing results only for the second batch.**

**Example -**

```
# profile a single batch, e.g. the 5th batch.
tensorboard_callback =
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', profile_batch=5)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
# run the tensorboard command to view the visualizations in profile plugin.

# profile a range of batches, e.g. from 10 to 20.
tensorboard_callback =
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', profile_batch='10,20')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
# run the tensorboard command to view the visualizations in profile plugin.
```

Set `profile_batch=0` to disable profiling. Must run in TensorFlow eager mode.

Comment: @Aniket Bote - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.

Comment: Can you take a look at my latest TensorFlow question @Tensorflow Warriors

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors The TF documentation is kind of obscure, though. How does showing only the second batch explain the misalignment between training and testing? Those two should have the same number of steps regardless of which batch we're looking at.